# React Expo WebView not playing video only sound

Tags: android, reactjs, expo

My WebView in Expo only works to play youtube videos, but nothing else. I have tried searching on the internet but haven't found anything that works.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <View style={{ height: 300 }}>

            <WebView
                    style={ styles.WebViewContainer }
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    source={{uri: someVideoURL }}
            />

        </View>

    );
  }
}
```

I tried using:

```
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}
```

But the error is the same. Sound works and lenght works, but video image is just white.